# Transposing a column to rows in python

Tags: python

I’m working with this data in python, the file has been converted to data frame in jupyter notebook. I want to transpose name column into rows but, keep all other columns untouched, the value column will be used as values to the new transposed columns. I want all of this to be in one data frame.

I have added a snapshot of the file before and after transposing the column.

[image]
[image]

Could you please help?

Comment: Why did you tag this Python? There's only an external link to an image of an Excel sheet.

Comment: OK, now I can see what you're trying to do. You actually have groups of rows (with the same transaction ID, apparently) and they need to be re-formatted into a single row, adding new columns with headings from 'name' and values from 'value'. Not trivial, but doable. I could easily code this in plain Python, but you're probably looking for a suitable `df` construct that does this in a single operation. My time budget for today is over, I will return to this tomorrow. Maybe someone else will beat me and provide an answer earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Use [pandas.DataFrame.T](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
transposed_df = df.T
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your comments, I have added a snapshot showing what the file should look like after transposing.